# Reinstall virtualbox on kubuntu 13.10

Tags: virtualbox

I've been running virtual box 4.3.6 with the  latest guest addition perfectly but an upgrade appeared and I tried to upgrade to 4.3.8 and then a message of broken virtual box appeared. I tried many forums for help but in the end a message appears:

"The package virtualbox-4.3 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it."

Also my ubuntu software center and synaptic package manager are not working. 
I cannot uninstall either.

I got this notifications
"An internal system error has occured
E: The package virtualbox-4.3 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it. E: Unable to apply corrections for half-installed packages"

Comment: You can download VirtualBox 4.3.6 [Here](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Download_Old_Builds_4_3).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the already installed virtualbox by running the below command,

```
sudo dpkg -P --force-remove-reinstreq virtualbox-4.3
```

Then download the virtualbox.deb file from [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Download_Old_Builds_4_3).And install it by running,

```
sudo dpkg -i filename.deb
```

Comment: running sudo dpkg -P virtualbox-4.3                             dpkg: error processing virtualbox-4.3 (--purge):
 Package is in a very bad inconsistent state - you should
 reinstall it before attempting a removal.
Errors were encountered while processing:
 virtualbox-4.3

Comment: rahul@rahul-desktop:~$ sudo dpkg -P --force-remove-reinstreq virtualbox-4.3
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
 Package is in a very bad inconsistent state - you should
 reinstall it before attempting a removal.
(Reading database ... 295812 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing virtualbox-4.3 ...
Stopping VirtualBox kernel modules ...done.
Purging configuration files for virtualbox-4.3 ...
...
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot

Comment: yes done.Then download the virtualbox.deb file and install it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the uninstall command in your terminal.

sudo apt-get --purge remove "here your application name without double quots"

If you give remove command only it will delete applications only but not delete packages.

So you need to give purge also

Comment: no still getting the same message

Comment: what message did u got

Comment: did you uninstall from the ubuntu software applications or using the commands

Comment: software center not running because of this issue and I've quoted the message

Comment: I have only one option, command line

Answer (score 0):

Rather that upgrading VirtualBox from the Virtual Box Manager or by downloading and installing a DEBIAN package it is recommended to add the Oracle repository to our `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian <release> contrib
```

Replace `<release>` with your Ubuntu release code name (e.g. `saucy`).

We additionally have to import the public key for this repository to be able to use it:

```
wget -q http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/oracle_vbox.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
```

We can then install or upgrade VirtualBox with our package manager by

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-<x.x> ## for installing
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade ## for upgrade
```

Replace `<x.x>` with the VirtualBox release version (e.g. `4.3.`).

By doing so we make sure that we automatically upgrade a new VirtualBox release whenever it is available. For major release upgrades (e.g. upgrade from 4.2. to 4.3.) we need to purge the old release first.

Comment: rahul@rahul-desktop:~$ deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian saucy contrib
No command 'deb' found, did you mean:
 Command 'debi' from package 'devscripts' (main)
 Command 'debc' from package 'devscripts' (main)
 Command 'xdeb' from package 'xdeb' (universe)
 Command 'dab' from package 'bsdgames' (universe)
 Command 'dwb' from package 'dwb' (universe)
 Command 'derb' from package 'libicu-dev' (main)
deb: command not found

Comment: rahul@rahul-desktop:~$ wget -q http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/oracle_vbox.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
[sudo] password for rahul: 
OK

Comment: rahul@rahul-desktop:~$ sudo apt-get update
Ign http://archive.canonical.com precise InRelease
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security InRelease                                  
Ign http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com precise ...
Reading package lists... Done
rahul@rahul-desktop:~$ sudo apt-get install virtualbox-4.3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package virtualbox-4.3 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.

Comment: rahul@rahul-desktop:~$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package virtualbox-4.3 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.

Comment: @user253178: in case you are not experienced with **editing** `sources.list` file you can also add repositories in *Software Sources* from the Software Center or Update Manager settings. Did you purge your broken 4.3.6?